# Ignore namespace to create nodelist in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm parsing a XML string to generate nodes. Sometimes the tag comes with a namespace & sometimes without namespace. How can I ignore this and

I tried in the following way, but it didnt work.

```
//NodeList idDetails =  doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "details");

NodeList idDetails = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:details");
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one shall work.

`NodeList nodes = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("*", str);`

But you have to also call `DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)` for this to work, otherwise namespaces will not be detected.

Comment: Thanks Optional. It works by setting namespaceaware as true